# Yammer SDK urls, which one to use?

Tags: yammer

can you please confirm which yammer SDK to use for embed feed?

We are using **https://assets.yammer.com**/assets/platform_embed.js. however the code and embed works ok.

But when we check at  https://developer.yammer.com/connect/#feed and 
https://developer.yammer.com/yammer-sdks,

It is mentioned to use 
 src="**https://c64.assets-yammer.com**/assets/platform_embed.js"

Kindly confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/* is the most recent one. It was updated in April,  2014 with some  new security features. That said, you may not need to change anything if your app is working as it should. Should you decide to use it, ensure you test it out properly first.